# Can I fail the build based on svn:eol-style and svn:keywords?

Tags: svn, build-automation

Not everyone I work with has subversion configured the same way. Every once in a while I have to make sure that all source files have the proper eol-style and keyword expansion set. It would be much easier if I could just fail the build if someone commits code without configuring subversion properly. Is that possible?

**EDIT**

The build uses maven kicked off from TeamCity, but I'm willing to set up a new build to make this happen.

Comment: Funny, we were just having the same discussion at work today. We have an in-house static analysis tool and were thinking about rolling our own test using SVNKit to grab the relevant properties from the working copy.

Comment: Sounds more like a task for a pre-commit hook to me. But you might also try messing with `svn propget` in your build/test scripts.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but I don't see you getting many concrete answers unless you mention what build system your process is based on (e.g., `make`, `ant`, `rake`, ...).

Comment: If you have implemented continuous integration then all hell breaks loose if there is a failed build. This is a necessary evil so that the line stays stable. Implementing this hook would raise an alarm for every eol-style error. This demeans the importance of a failed build. .... Its your call to decide whether a eol-style error should have the same importance as a 'real' failed build?

Comment: That's why we use TeamCity, for the pre-commit remote runs. We allow CheckStyle to fail the build which is similar, and hell hasn't broken loose.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you set up a pre-commit hook script on your server, so that commits which don't have the keywords or properties set get rejected and the user has to fix that.

There are example hook scripts available for this here:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/

the 'svn-keyword-check.pl' and 'pre-commit-check.py' are the ones you should look at.